# How do I get a new table entry from a changing cell value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a IMPORTXML formula to get just one specific value from a website. This value is changing over time. I also have a Table with one entry for each time that value changes and the date on which it did. So say the value changes from 2000 to 2034 and the next day to 2045 my table would look something like this:

Date Value

```
15.04.2022  2000

15.04.2022  2034

16.04.2022  2045
```

Now I'm looking for a formula that automates this process and creates a new entry with the corresponding timestamp every time the value changes.

I have automated a lot in the sheet already but I just can't find a way to do this last thing. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TeAE31POoAUqO7npROeU0PBj35eWxgBQQs8gSyY7Oww/edit?usp=sharing) is a very simplified version of my Spreadsheet. Under Current SR is the Value that will update and it's supposed to add another row under the examples.

Edit 2:
I was able to solve the problem, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You may need scripting (google apps script) to do that.

Comment: You just have to copy the results in a new row each time that value changes by script. Share a simplified spreadsheet.

Comment: I see, I've never heard of Google Apps Script, I will look into it. I've also shared a simplified spreadsheet.